# Migrating users to Identity Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a large subset of WordPress users in a MySQL database who I want to migrate to Identity Server 4/5.

While I could easily select the data and insert into the ASPNetUsers table, **my concern** is:

1. I'm bypassing the controlling application (Identity Server)
2. Also there appears to be, two cryptographic fields in ASPNetUsers table (SecurityStamp
   and ConcurrencyStamp) which I don't know how to generate data for. Not populating them feels like it could lead to interesting side-effects.

What is the best practice in importing a large subset of users programmatically into Identity Server?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 2 values just need to be random and in the correct format and don't in themselves hold any meaning. They're just used to check if the DB record has changed since it was loaded.

The main thing to worry about is migration of password hashes. We solved this by having a back channel call to the source system to validate the password the first time the user signs in and then updated the local PasswordHash once we'd verified the provided password was valid.

Comment: Thanks! I moved the Wordpress hashed passwords into ASPNetUsers and validate them when the user logs in at IdentityServer. PHPPass algorithm used by WP contains the salt in the hashed password, so it makes it a dream to migrate.